"Remix Vite - Module Federation Microfrontend" failed to expose and fetch (remote, host)
I'm trying to implement Module Federation with Remix.run and Vite.
I've tried with React vanilla using the same method and works flawlessly but failed when I tried to use it with Remix.run latest (Vite).
Current Packages:
"@originjs/vite-plugin-federation": "^1.3.5",
"@remix-run/node": "^2.10.3"

Current Settings (Remote):
app/components/Cardio.tsx
export function Cardio() {
  return <h1>Hello World from Cardio</h1>;
}

vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        remix(),
        federation({
            name: "remoteApp",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./Cardio": "./app/components/Cardio.tsx",
            },
            shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});

I've also tried this config (without importing react):
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        remix(),
        federation({
            name: "remoteApp",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./Cardio": "./app/components/Cardio.tsx",
            },
            shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});

when I ran yarn build (remix vite:build) it gives me the following rollup error:

Entry module "react-dom" cannot be external.

I also tried to use npx vite build, it successfully build but only client components, server components are not built, but I kept going just to test it.
Current Settings (Host):
vite.config.ts
import { vitePlugin as remix } from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import federation from "@originjs/vite-plugin-federation";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: "app",
            remotes: {
                remoteA: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
        }),
        remix({
            future: {
                v3_fetcherPersist: true,
                v3_relativeSplatPath: true,
                v3_throwAbortReason: true,
            },
        }),
        tsconfigPaths(),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});

and also tried without importing react, but then I use the component in my page and open it in my browser, it shows:

Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'http:'

I've also tried changing the plugins order bit still doesn't work.
Is there something I'm missing here or current Remix.run version is not available for Module Federation?

Funny thing, I'm going through the same exercise atm, would you mind sharing the guide you're using for this? I can't be helpful in any way to your issue atm, I went down the Fog of War path, if it helps. https://remix.run/docs/en/main/guides/fog-of-war

@A-SM do you have any luck with it? I'm testing as well but no success yet.

@user1595858 nope, haven't found a way
